# WordPress database error: column p.id does not exist | Wordpress using Postgres

Tags: php, wordpress, postgresql

I seem to have this error:

```
WordPress database error ERROR:  column p.id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT p.id FROM wp_posts AS p  WHERE p.post_date > '2013-01...
```

Coming from this block of code:

```
<?php
$posts=$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
 "SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s " .
 "ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(meta_value) DESC, meta_value DESC LIMIT 5",
 '_wp-svbtle-kudos'
));
?>
```

I'm using postgresql with wordpress. I implemented [this](https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku) and I am using [this](https://github.com/gravityonmars/wp-svbtle) theme. The problem is coming from Line 78 [here](https://github.com/gravityonmars/wp-svbtle/blob/master/wp-content/themes/svbtle/single.php).

For post the database looks like this:

[image]

And for postmeta it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that error is coming from *that* block of code? The SELECT statement in the error message doesn't match the SELECT statement in that block. Not even the same tables.

Comment: That's not where your error is coming from. The SQL you posted from line 78 doesn't match up with the SQL returned by the error.

Comment: I guess because when I affect that line of code, the error changes.

Comment: @bgadoci I wonder did you ever find the specific source of this issue, i have created the [heroku-wordpress-svbtle](https://github.com/webjames/heroku-wordpress-svbtle) repository on GitHub and can see a similar error in my Heroku logs, it doesn't seem to be affecting the app though, at least not in a way i've identified yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, I suspect that WordPress created the table like this.

```
create table "wp_posts" (
  "ID" int8 primary key,
  ...
);
```

In PostgreSQL, if you declare a column name using uppercase within double quotes, you have to access it the same way.

```
SELECT p."ID" FROM wp_posts p ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Postgres is picky on caps/no caps. The wordpress I installed had ID rather than id as the column name in the database. I did a grep -r 'p/.id' * and found p.id in wp-includes/link-template.php. On line 1177 I had 
$query = "SELECT p.id FROM $wpdb->posts AS p $join $where $sort";
which I changed to
$query = "SELECT p.ID FROM $wpdb->posts AS p $join $where $sort";
and the errors went away.

Comment: This indeed fixed it for us as well, running WP 3.5.0 with latest PG4WP.